# Combine two standalone class documents that have different formats

Tags: standalone

I would like to create a document using the standalone class, where some pages are in the regular A4 portrait format.

Others should look approximately like this:

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10cm 4cm 10cm 4cm}]{standalone}
```

The following example, however, does not work.

master

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\input{introduction}
\end{document}
```

subfile

```
\documentclass[preview,border={5cm 4cm 15cm 4cm}]{standalone}
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone} % causes problems 
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    {\boxed{\| \partial_t g^{jk} + 2 \omega g^{jk} \|_{H^N}  \leq C e^{-(2+q)\Omega} S_{g;N}}} \\
    \\
    {\boxed{\| \partial_t g^{jk} + 2 \omega g^{jk} \|_{L^{\infty}}  \leq C e^{-(2+q)\Omega} S_{g;N}}}
    \arrow["{\text{Sobolev embedding}}", from=1-1, to=3-1]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't what `standalone` does. It includes the contents of the `\input` file's `document` environment as if it was part of the main document. So if the main document's pages are A4, it typesets that content as part of an A4 page.

Comment: Ok, but how can I achieve my goal then?

Comment: Is the non-standard page supposed to include the section heading? What exactly is supposed to end up on each page and how is the page breaking to be done?

Comment: You can use the geometry package to create non-standard pages.  Actually, you can do the same without geometry, but it takes more lines of code.

Comment: What is your actual goal?  All you've told us is that you want your standalone files to have different page sizes, which isn't how they work.  But your actual goal is to have the smaller file's output show up in the main file in some manner.  The actual manner determines how we can make that happen.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `geometry` can't change paper sizes after `\begin{document}` if that's what's wanted. I'm not really clear if that's the goal or not.

Comment: it seems that I cannot attach pdf examples.
1. page A4
2.page the result of 
```
\documentclass[preview,border={5cm 4cm 15cm 4cm}]{standalone}
```
that tikzcd is simplified the original one is much larger this is why I have this border setting.
I could use pdfunite to clue together both pdf, but that is cumbersome